# Sending Mail Using Ajax.BeginForm Not Working On Server

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax.beginform

I am trying to send mail with using Ajax.BeginForm in Visual Studio 2013 MVC project.

It works on localhost or on IIS, i am sending mail with successfully but when i publish on server i am getting error like this :

```
jquery-3.3.1.js:9600 POST http://draskinkaraca.com/Home/SendMail 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Can you help me please what should i do ? Thank you very much.

Requested URL: /Home/SendMail

**Here is my Cshtml part;**

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SendMail", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "OnSuccess", OnFailure = "OnFailure" }))
        {
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                    <form>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Ad" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="surname" placeholder="Soyad" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tel" placeholder="Telefon" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <textarea rows="5" id="message" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Mesajınız"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" id="btnSendMail" class="btn">Gönder</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
```

**Here is my Controller Part;**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult SendMail(string name, string surname, string eMail, string tel, string message)
    {
        MailMessage ePosta = new MailMessage();
        ePosta.From = new MailAddress("info@xxxx.com");
        ePosta.To.Add("xxxx@hotmail.com");
        ePosta.Subject = "Siteden gelen mail !!";
        ePosta.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        ePosta.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        ePosta.Body = "Ad Soyad : " + name + " " + surname + System.Environment.NewLine +
        "Mail : " + eMail + System.Environment.NewLine +
        "Telefon : " + tel + System.Environment.NewLine +
        "Mesaj : " + message;
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        //
        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("info@xxxx.com", "xxxx");
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.Host = "webmail.xxxx.com";//webmail.xxxx.com

        smtp.EnableSsl = false;
        try
        {
            smtp.Send(ePosta);
        }
        catch (SmtpException ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Mail Gönderme Hatasi", ex.InnerException.InnerException);

        }

        var result = "success";
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**Here is my Scripts Jquery 3.3.1;**

```
 <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/Index.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/toastr.js">
```

Comment: `500 (Internal Server Error)` means your controller is throwing an exception - use you browsers tools (the Network tab) to inspect the response - it will contain details of the error

Comment: Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /Home/SendMail

Comment: Make sure you created a HomeController.cs class in your controller folder and generated dll is copied into right deployed folder.

Comment: I am sured it is in controller folder